# Dynamic matrix and C++: Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector, matrix, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matrix Arithmetic using Vectors in C++ causing segmentation faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347375/matrix-arithmetic-using-vectors-in-c-causing-segmentation-faults)

I created this simple code in C++ to assign some values to a dynamic matrix:

```
unsigned N = 1000;
vector<vector<double> > Matrix;

for (unsigned i=0; i<(N-1); ++i) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<(N-1); ++j) {

        if ((i>(N/4-1) && i<(3*N/4-1)) || (j>(N/4-1) && j<(3*N/4-1)))
            Matrix[i][j] = 1;

        else if (i==0 || i==(N-1) || j==0 || j==(N-1))
            Matrix[i][j] = 0;
}
}
```

The compiler does not return any problem, but when I try to run the program, it returns: Segmentation Fault. Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just creating two empty vectors, and using the `operator[]` is undefined behaviour. They are like arrays of size 0, if such a thing was possible.

You have to create the vectors with a capacity, and each element will be default-initialised to 0:

```
vector<vector<double>> Matrix(N, vector<double>(N));
```

The first argument is the size of the outer `vector`, and the second is the value to copy into each element, which is itself a vector of `N` doubles.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you have listed is the exact code causing the problem, your issue is that you haven't actually given the "matrix" a size.

```
vector<vector<double> > Matrix ( N, vector<double>(N) );
```

would do that.

In future to debug segfaults, you can start with by compiling with no optimisations and debug symbols on, then running in a debugger (such as gdb) and backtracing after the sefault. The backtrace would also be useful when asking for help.